# Delphi Load Blob from MySql

Tags: mysql, delphi

in my project i use mysql.pas to deal with MySql database , so i've this Table structure :

```
Table Name :CarsTbl
ID  int 10
CarName varchar 100
Car_Img longblob 0
```

i use this table to save each Car with its name and its picture .
The save routine works very well .

But the problem is when getting the Car_Img in which i use the following procedure :

```
procedure GetCarImage(const MyCarName:String;TrgStream:TMemoryStream);
var
  query_string: String;
  rCount: Integer;
  mySQL_Res: PMYSQL_RES;
  LibH: PMYSQL;
  Row: PMYSQL_ROW;
  iLen:PMYSQL_LENGTHS;
begin
   mySQL_Res := nil;
   Try
    Try
   query_string := 'SELECT CarName,Car_Img FROM CarsTbl WHERE CarName="'+MyCarName+'"';
   mysql_real_query(LibH, PAnsiChar(query_string), Length(query_string));
    mySQL_Res := mysql_store_result(LibH);
    Try
    rCount := mysql_num_rows(mySQL_Res);
        If rCount > 0 Then Begin
          Repeat
            Row := mysql_fetch_row(mySQL_Res);
            iLen:= mysql_fetch_lengths(mySQL_Res);
            If Row <> nil Then Begin
            TrgStream.position :=0;
            //Row^[1] ==== Car_Img Blob Field
            TrgStream.WriteBuffer(Row^[1],iLen[1]);
            End;
          Until Row = nil;
          end;
      Finally
        mysql_free_result(mySQL_Res);
        mySQL_Res := nil;
        Row := nil;
      End;
    Finally
      mysql_close(LibH);
    End;

  Finally
    LibH := nil;
  End;
end;
```

I get the Car image but with Malformed file Header let me explain : 
Audi_Car image is saved as a Png image , but when i Load its image i always get it like this :

[image]

So please how could correct this ? is there any error in my Sql query ?

P.S : **i create TrgStream in an other place.**

And here's my LoadCarImage Procedure :

```
Procedure LoadCarImage();
var
CarStrm:TMemoryStream;
begin
CarStrm:=TMemoryStream.Create;
Try
GetCarImage('Audi',CarStrm);
CarStrm.SaveToFile('audi.png');
finally
    CarStrm.Free;
    end;
end;
```

many thanks

Comment: How do you know that the "save routine works very well"? Can you extract the column content some other way and examine it to make sure it's saved correctly to the database? If it's corrupted or damaged while being saved, it can't be read back out properly. Also, where are you saving the stream contents? Your code doesn't show that information.

Comment: @Ken White many thanks , for your 1st question Yes i though about it so i used MySQLWorkbench just to test it so load a png file into the Blob Field ( So the save is done manually ) .
For your 2nd question i will edit my Thread and add the Load procedure

Comment: I edited my thread to add the LoadCarImage procedure .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not use

```
  Repeat ...  until
```

`CarName` is not unique. So if you have more than one `Audi` in your table you create also a not valid image file.

Try it with

Delphi5

EDIT:

With
`TrgStream.WriteBuffer(Row^[1],iLen[1]);`

WriteBuffer takes the first pointer and writing the content of the whole Row.
In your .png file now you have

```
ID00CarName00Car_Img 

9Wî00f­î00Audi00‰PNG.......
```

I prefer the long way via the array only to see what I get.

Now that you have tested it. we have found no error in the writing of the present stream.
we use instead of
`TrgStream.WriteBuffer(Row^[1],iLen[1]);`
this
`TrgStream.WriteBuffer(Row^[1]^,iLen[1]);`

```
procedure GetCarImage(const MyCarName:String;TrgStream:TMemoryStream);
var
  [...]


begin
  [...]

    query_string := 'SELECT CarName,Car_Img FROM cars WHERE CarName="Audi"';
    mysql_real_query(LibH, PAnsiChar(query_string), Length(query_string));
    mySQL_Res := mysql_store_result(LibH);
    Try
    rCount := mysql_num_rows(mySQL_Res);
        If rCount > 0 Then Begin

            Row := mysql_fetch_row(mySQL_Res);
            iLen:= mysql_fetch_lengths(mySQL_Res);
            If Row <> nil Then Begin
            TrgStream.position :=0;
            //Row^[1] ==== Car_Img Blob Field
            TrgStream.WriteBuffer(Row^[1]^,iLen[1]);
    [...]
```

Comment: @ moskito-x , many thanks it works , Just i want to know : why my code didn't give the same result ?
many thanks again

Comment: @user1998327 : As I said you should also test `if rCount > 1 Then error` . You can not write to the stream, content with more than a blob. Thus you get an invalid file. The repeat ... until block is wrong here. That's why I left it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the allmost same problem.
I  wanted read emf  (picture metafile) from  mysql glob field.
And I solved  it  like this.

```
var
  text_t1:string;
  Stream: TStream;

begin
  text_t1:='';
  text_t1:=' select emf_glob from table ';
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(text_t1);
  ADOQuery1.Open;
  ADOQuery1.first;

  Stream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
  Stream := ADOQuery1.CreateBlobStream(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('emf_glob'), bmRead); 
  Stream.Position:=0;
  DBImage1.Picture.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  Stream.Free;
```